# Set column as primary key if the table doesn't have a primary key

Tags: t-sql

I have a column in db which has 5 columns but no primary key.
One of the columns is named myTable_id and is integer.

I want to check if the table has a primary key column. If it doesn't, then make myTable_id a primary key column and make it identity column. Is there a way to do this?

I tried with this:

```
ALTER TABLE Persons
DROP CONSTRAINT pk_PersonID

ALTER TABLE Persons
ADD PRIMARY KEY (P_Id)
```

and I get syntax error in Management studio.

Comment: you should mark one answer as accepted.

Answer (score 51):

This checks if primary key exists, if not it is created

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS 
WHERE CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY' AND TABLE_NAME = 'Persons' 
AND TABLE_SCHEMA ='dbo')
BEGIN
   ALTER TABLE Persons ADD CONSTRAINT pk_PersonID PRIMARY KEY (P_Id)
END
ELSE
BEGIN
   -- Key exists
END
```

fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e165d/2

Answer (score 7):

```
ALTER TABLE Persons
ADD CONSTRAINT pk_PersonID PRIMARY KEY (P_Id)
```

Comment: how about identity column?

Comment: "I want to check if the table has a primary key column" was not addressed.

Answer (score 3):

An `IDENTITY` constraint **can't be added to an existing column**, so how you add this needs to be your initial thought. There are two options:

1. Create a new table including a primary key with identity and drop the existing table
2. Create a new primary key column with identity and drop the existing 'P_ID' column

There is a third way, which is a better approach for very large tables via the `ALTER TABLE...SWITCH` statement. See [Adding an `IDENTITY` to an existing column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049210/adding-an-identity-to-an-existing-column) for an example of each. In answer to this question, if the table isn't too large, I recommend running the following:

```
-- Check that the table/column exist and no primary key is already on the table. 
IF COL_LENGTH('PERSONS','P_ID') IS NOT NULL
   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS 
                   WHERE CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY' AND TABLE_NAME = 'PERSONS')
                   -- Add table schema to the WHERE clause above e.g. AND TABLE_SCHEMA ='dbo'
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE PERSONS    
    ADD P_ID_new int IDENTITY(1, 1)
    GO

    ALTER TABLE PERSONS 
    DROP COLUMN P_ID
    GO

    EXEC sp_rename 'PERSONS.P_ID_new', 'P_ID', 'Column'
    GO

    ALTER TABLE PERSONS 
    ADD CONSTRAINT PK_P_ID PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (P_ID)
    GO
END
```

**Notes:**
By explicitly using the `CONSTRAINT` keyword the primary key constraint is given a particular name rather than depending on SQL Server to auto-assign a name.

Only include `CLUSTERED` on the `PRIMARY KEY` if the balance of searches for a particular P_ID and the amount of writing outweighs the benefits of clustering the table by some other index. See [Create SQL `IDENTITY` as `PRIMARY KEY`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355349/create-sql-identity-as-primary-key).

Answer (score 2):

You can check if primary key exists or not using [OBJECTPROPERTY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176105.aspx) Transact SQL, use `'TableHasPrimaryKey'` for the second arguments.

```
DECLARE @ISHASPRIMARYKEY INT;

SELECT @ISHASPRIMARYKEY = OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('PERSONS'), 'TABLEHASPRIMARYKEY');
IF @ISHASPRIMARYKEY IS NULL 
BEGIN
   -- generate identity column
   ALTER TABLE PERSONS
   DROP COLUMN P_ID;

   ALTER TABLE PERSONS
   ADD P_ID INT IDENTITY(1,1);

   -- add primary key
   ALTER TABLE PERSONS
   ADD CONSTRAINT PK_PERSONID PRIMARY KEY (P_ID);

END;
```

Comment: I think @ISHASPRIMARYKEY will only be null if the Persons table doesn't exist, otherwise it will be 0 or 1 depending on the existence of a primary key.

Comment: @KnarfaLingus - you are correct.  I have made an edit but my rep is not high enough at this time so I have to wait for it to be approved.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that. For making a column into an identity column I think you have to drop the table entirely.

Comment: You can't convert to identity but you can add an identity to a table